# Linking an Image both hosting Laravel on a shared host and developing on localhost

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I have hosted my Laravel project a shared host.

The website involves accessing the image in a public folder linked to a storage folder. My local host  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/305834409.jpg` is accessible.

However. my hosted website at `https://www.api.dormi.co.tz/storage/images/305834409.jpg` returns a **404 Not Found** error.

What is the possible solution?

Comment: Presumably either you did not upload the image to the host, or it's not at that location